# Seasonal difference in ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

I have time  series with frequency=7. `ndiffs`function (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.10/topics/ndiffs) suggests first order difference .

`kpss.test` from tseries package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-47/topics/kpss.test) suggests first order difference as well for (null="Trend"),  while `nsdiffs` function tells that seasonal difference is not required. (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.10/topics/nsdiffs).
[image: Time series]
ACF GRAPH of the series. 
[image: ACF of time series]

After the first order difference the following ACF and PACF graphs are constructed:

[image]

[image]

Time series itself after difference looks like this:[image]

It looks stationary and passes previously mentioned unit root tests, but ACF and PACF graphs made me thinking.

Seasonality doesn't appear to die out in ACF graph. My question is: what should I do with it ? Is seasonal difference required or should I just model it with ARIMA(p,1,q)(P,0,0)7 model, where p,q and P parameters are modeled to minimize AIC?

Comment: post your data and I will try and help further.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/119RXtTVJbHYeivorEtApbxQrLkLXolZdOc0kgCXFljQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you could help it would nice, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primary issue with your 468 daily values is the presence of a number of anomalies. I took your data into AUTOBOX ( which I have helped to develop) and it simultaneously idenifies both the arima component ( 1,0,0)(1,0,0)7 and a number of evidented anomalies.

[image] presents the Actual/Fit and Forecast. The model is here[image] and here [image] with statistics here [image]

The residual plot is here [image]

There is no need for differencing of any order. The software you are using "gets confused by anomalies" as it tacitely assumes there non-existence.

95% prediction limits allowing for future anomalies is here [image] . Note that if one were to assume that no anomalies will happen in the future then the 95% limits are much tighter and probably more misleading.

Hope this helps you and other readers.

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful !

Comment: If you like my answr , please accept it to close the question.....